# The 'Switch-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup' command was found in the module 'Az.Sql', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I am trying to write a Powershell script that makes use of the `Switch-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup` cmdlet. The script is to be executed in an automation runbook, and I have successfully installed the `Az.Sql` module to the automation account. However, whenever I run the book, I get the following error:

```
Switch-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup : The 'Switch-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup' command was found in the module 'Az.Sql', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Sql'. 

At line:42 char:5 
+ Switch-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup ` 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Switch-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

I have tried executing the same script on my local machine (with the `Az.Sql` module installed) and am getting the same error.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

They both work fine on my side. I can also reproduce your issue, I suppose you use the old `Connect-AzureRmAccount` module to login, you need to use `Connect-AzAccount`, just use the script as below.

[image]

In the automation account, I use `Az.Accounts 1.6.4` and `Az.Sql 2.0.0`, you can also try the same version with me, just delete the old module, navigate to the `Browse Gallery`, search and import them again.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Switch-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name > -ServerName <secondary-server-of-failover-group> -FailoverGroupName <failover-group-name>
```

Comment: Hi Joy, thanks for your response. I'm currently using `Connect-AzureRmAccount` to login, and am using the same versions of the modules as you. I'll change to `Connect-AzAccount` later today and test it.

Comment: @Cam Well, good luck. If it works, don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: @Cam Could you get it now?

Comment: Hi Joy sorry I haven't had a chance to test it - I will let you know when I have been able to